# Attempt at ASP.NET MVC App SDL Digital Experience Accelerator 1.3 Error

Tags: 2013, dxa, mvc

Attempting to to set up a new  ASP.NET MVC application  for custom development of DXA site on the POC instance using the following [URL](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-482760DF-5287-4246-BBBE-65786B45757E#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-B2F30A0E-8BC5-4DDB-B168-B2C7280F5CD8.xml&docid=GUID-B2F30A0E-8BC5-4DDB-B168-B2C7280F5CD8&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B2F30A0E-8BC5-4DDB-B168-B2C7280F5CD8):

[image]

Stack Trace:

```
 [ConfigurationException: <JavaException>
<Type>com/tridion/configuration/ConfigurationException</Type>
<Message><![CDATA[Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized.]]></Message>
<StackTrace><![CDATA[com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized.
at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup()
at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
```

```
 Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup() +616
 Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +63
 System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
 System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
 System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): <JavaException>
<Type>com/tridion/configuration/ConfigurationException</Type>
<Message><![CDATA[Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized.]]></Message>
<StackTrace><![CDATA[com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized.
 at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.Setup()
 at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
 at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
```

```
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712
```

I have read alot of posts on this, some about 64-bit/32-bit versions and xmogrt but all is aligning up from what I checked. I have checked java versions, reset iis, anyone run into this error and/or steps to get it up and running from Windows Server 2012 r2?

Its the same box DXA is currently running successfully on.. Haven't ruled out license file, but should be correct from what was initially requested from support.

I do not see anything in the logs (they are configured correctly). All I see in Windows Application logs is the same as stack trace above.

[image]

Comment: When you say you do not see anything in the logs, do you mean the logs are empty, or that there are no errors? There should at least be something in cd_core....log

Comment: The error "Ambient Data Framework configuration was not properly initialized" suggests that ADF is not properly setup - can you verify the tridion config files, tridion JAR files and application web.config are all in sync to support the ADF?

Comment: validate cd_ambient_conf.xml & cd_ambient.jar for permission and "Unblock" in properties.